# Program uninstalled but still gives error: ContextualVersionConflict

Tags: apt, 18.04, uninstall

I use ubuntu 18.04.
I recently installed certbot to create an SSH and it worked. Then I decide to install `python-pip` and `certbot-dns-cloudflare` using this command

```
sudo apt install python-pip
sudo pip install certbot-dns-cloudflare
```

after installing, when I ran `certbot` I always get the error

```
An unexpected error occurred:
ContextualVersionConflict: (cryptography 2.1.4 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('cryptography>=2.2.1'), set(['PyOpenSSL']))
Please see the logfile '/tmp/tmpg0HmH3' for more details.
```

the log file output:

```
2019-01-08 01:54:07,629:DEBUG:certbot.log:Exiting abnormally:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/certbot", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 1334, in main
    plugins = plugins_disco.PluginsRegistry.find_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot/plugins/disco.py", line 206, in find_all
    plugin_ep = PluginEntryPoint(entry_point)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot/plugins/disco.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.plugin_cls = entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2323, in load
    self.require(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2346, in require
    items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer, extras=self.extras)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 783, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
ContextualVersionConflict: (cryptography 2.1.4 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('cryptography>=2.2.1'), set(['PyOpenSSL']))
2019-01-08 01:54:07,629:ERROR:certbot.log:An unexpected error occurred:
```

even when I uninstalled `python-pip` `certbot-dns-cloudflare` and `certbot` using

```
sudo pip uninstall certbot-dns-cloudflare
sudo apt remove python-pip
sudo apt remove certbot
```

I still got the same error, shouldn't it tells me that the program is not installed?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it with the solution posted [here](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/not-sure-how-to-proceed-dont-know-if-certbot-or-other-issue/89337).

The “cryptography” had to be upgraded. I used

```
pip install cryptography --upgrade
```

and updated the package and then all Certbot commands worked without any errors!

Comment: Including more information from the link provided would improve the quality of your answer.